# filtering cakedc search results

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i'm using cakeDC's search plugin in my app. can;t seem to figure out why the results are empty if i pass no value in the username field i'm searching but have the account type filter set to either admin or user *For the record, having the filter set to all with the username field empty will output all the users in the system* trying to replicate the behavior of searches having the account type filter set to all with an empty  username search field for having the account type filter set to either 2 user types

here's the relevant code if needed:

controller

```
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session','Search.Prg');
public $presetVars = array(
array('field' => 'username', 'type' => 'value'),
array('field' => 'account_type', 'type' => 'value'));
public function admin_index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => $this->User->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs));
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate(),'session',$this->Session);
```

model

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

    public $filterArgs = array(   array('name' => 'username', 'type' => 'query', 'method' => 'filterName'),
        array('name' => 'account_type', 'type' => 'value'),
    );

    public function filterName($data, $field = null) {

        $nameField = '%' . $data['username'] . '%';
        return array(
            'OR' => array(
                $this->alias . '.username LIKE' => $nameField,
                ));
    }
```

view search form

```
<div><?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
        'novalidate' =>true,'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index','admin'=> true), $this->params['pass'])
        )); ?>
    <?php 
    $account_types = array(
                '' => __('All', true),
                 0 => __('admin', true),
                 1 => __('user', true),);
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true)); // empty creates blank option.
    echo $this->Form->input('account_type', array('label' => 'account_type', 'options' => $account_types));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?></div>
```

Comment: The `OR` in your returned conditions doesn't make much sense, as there is only 1 check (the username LIKE).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 'empty' and allowEmpty in username and account_type like this:

```
public $filterArgs = array(   array('name' => 'username', 'type' => 'query', 'method' => 'filterName', 'empty'=>true, 'allowEmpty'=>true),
    array('name' => 'account_type', 'type' => 'value','empty'=>true, 'allowEmpty'=>true),
);
```

I had this kind of behavior as well from CakeDC/search and this two configs saved me, hope it will do for you as well.

It's a good idea to check the queries being executed as well using [DebugKit.Toolbar](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit).